# Scala - Apply a function to each value in a dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a function that takes a `LocalDate` (it could take any other type) and returns a `DataFrame`, e.g.:

```
def genDataFrame(refDate: LocalDate): DataFrame = {
  Seq(
    (refDate,refDate.minusDays(7)),
    (refDate.plusDays(3),refDate.plusDays(7))
  ).toDF("col_A","col_B")
}
```

`genDataFrame(LocalDate.parse("2021-07-02"))` output:

```
+----------+----------+
|     col_A|     col_B|
+----------+----------+
|2021-07-02|2021-06-25|
|2021-07-05|2021-07-09|
+----------+----------+
```

I wanna apply this function to each element in a dataframe column (which contains, obviously, `LocalDate` values), such as:

```
val myDate = LocalDate.parse("2021-07-02")

val df = Seq(
  (myDate),
  (myDate.plusDays(1)),
  (myDate.plusDays(3))
).toDF("date")
```

`df`:

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2021-07-02|
|2021-07-03|
|2021-07-05|
+----------+
```

Required output:

```
+----------+----------+
|     col_A|     col_B|
+----------+----------+
|2021-07-02|2021-06-25|
|2021-07-05|2021-07-09|
|2021-07-03|2021-06-26|
|2021-07-06|2021-07-10|
|2021-07-05|2021-06-28|
|2021-07-08|2021-07-12|
+----------+----------+
```

How could I achieve that (without using `collect`)?

Comment: Can you post an example output of `genDataFrame`? Is the second column a `tuple`? How would your function output look like for a single date? It doesn't seem to me like that would match what you've written as your required output format (minus 7 days , (plus 3 days, plus 7 days))

Comment: Hi, @RandomnessSlayer. `genDataFrame` simply yields a DataFrame from a scalar input -  in this example, a `2x2` DataFrame. I want a `2n x 2` when this function is applied in a `n x 1` DataFrame. I edited the question to show a `genDataFrame` output example.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert your data frame to a lazily evaluated view and use Spark SQL:

```
val df_2 = df.map(x => x.getDate(0).toLocalDate()).withColumnRenamed("value", "col_A")
.withColumn("col_B", col("col_A"))
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
```

With that you can create a view like this one:

```
+----------+----------+
|     col_A|     col_B|
+----------+----------+
|2021-07-02|2021-07-02|
|2021-07-03|2021-07-03|
|2021-07-05|2021-07-05|
+----------+----------+
```

And then you can use SQL wich I find more intuitive:

```
spark.sql(s"""SELECT col_A, date_add(col_B, -7) as col_B FROM test
UNION
SELECT date_add(col_A, 3), date_add(col_B, 7) as col_B FROM test""")
.show()
```

This gives your expected output as a DataFrame:

```
+----------+----------+
|     col_A|     col_B|
+----------+----------+
|2021-07-02|2021-06-25|
|2021-07-03|2021-06-26|
|2021-07-05|2021-06-28|
|2021-07-05|2021-07-09|
|2021-07-06|2021-07-10|
|2021-07-08|2021-07-12|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jaime Caffarel, but I can't use it: first, the real `genDataFrame` can't be translated to SQL (I just illustrate the process `LocalDate => DataFrame`; second, the whole process should run inside an infra that accepts only Scala, so I can't use SQL or Views.